# How to accessing Dropbox files system from Windows 7 Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, dropbox

- Webfolders do not work with dropbox (or how to enable?)
- WebDAV is not supported

i used **dropdav** but they promised to be free as long as Dropbox provides free access but immediately started charging for sservice. also they have protocol bugs with free and paid service it breaks batch copy operation

What to do?

Comment: Why don't you use the Dropbox application?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has its own application for integrating your Dropbox folders into Windows Explorer. It will add a 'Dropbox' folder alongside your Documents, Music, etc., and will automatically synchronize between that folder and your Dropbox storage. The application can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/downloading).

You might also look into something called [Otixo](http://otixo.com/). I haven't used it myself, but it looks like it will do what you want. There are some instructions on using it [here](http://sumtips.com/2011/07/create-network-drive-access-file-cloud.html).

Comment: This is kinda opposite result - letting Dropbox to access my file system. Anyway, their utility cannot work outside predefined root.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I found something else, and edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

As i can see, basically you want to mount Dropbox file system as a folder or drive in Windows file explorer. I so far have not been able to find an open source application that would allow me do it.

Speaking of proprietry applications, you've got choices:

- [Storage Made Easy](http://www.storagemadeeasy.com/)
- [DropDAV](https://www.dropdav.com/)

There might be more but i have not investigated further. These two applications will let you mount file systems via WebDav in file explorer and treat them as drives with designated drive letter. From what i can see i like Storage Made Easy better, more functional. Both are paid applications.